# how to make a rotate animation in css angular

Tags: html, css, angular

i am using angular and my question is simple how can i make to rotate this icon when i click on it?:

```
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-2 alend-text">
        <i class="pomrgto iconfa fas fa-chevron-circle-right view_cir" title="Ver" aria-hidden="true" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
            [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseBasic"></i>
    </div>
```

the icon is the `pomrgto iconfa fas fa-chevron-circle-right view_cir` class, i want to do this:

[image]

When i click the icon, i want to make this rotate 90 degrees to the right making a little rotate animation, and when i click again go to the original state...

[image]

I know i can do it with css, but can you give me an idea of how can i do that?

Thank you!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this:

By default set transition property on the arrow.
On click of the icon, add a new class to it (let say "active")
then in CSS:

```css
.pomrgto{
  transition: transform 1s;
 }

.active{
  transform: rotate(90deg)
}
```